# Spark: Extract zipped keys without computing values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Spark has a [`zip()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.zip) function to combine two RDDs.  It also has functions to split them apart again: [`keys()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.keys) and [`values()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.values).  But to my surprise, if you ask for just the `keys()`, both RDDs are fully computed, even if the values weren't necessary for the computation.

In this example, I create an RDD of `(key, value)` pairs, but then I only ask for the keys.  Why are the values computed anyway?  Does Spark make no attempt to simplify it's internal DAG in such cases?

```py
In [1]: def process_value(val):
   ...:     print "Processing {}".format(val)
   ...:     return 2*val
   ...:

In [2]: k = sc.parallelize(['a','b','c'])

In [3]: v = sc.parallelize([1,2,3]).map(process_value)

In [4]: zipped = k.zip(v)

In [5]: zipped.keys().collect()
Processing 1
Processing 2
Processing 3

Out[5]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L1249) (at least at 2.0) keys() is simply implemented as

`rdd.map(_._1)`

I.e. returning the first attribute of the tuple, so the tuple must be fully instantiated.

This might have worked if zip returned `RDD[Seq[K, V]]` or some other lazy data structure, but a tuple is not a lazy data structure.

In short: no.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is an alternative to `keys()` that avoids computing the values?

Comment: I am by no means an expert, but I don't think that RDDs really have enough visibility into their values to do what you want